# how to set data in Bean2 from Bean1

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, javabeans, view-scope

What I have is below.

### Bean1.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean1")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean1 {
    public String username;
    // some variables and getter and setter
    public String sendPassword() {
        String emailIdToSend = data from database with respect to username with below query
        //SELECT emailId FROM userSysInfo WHERE username=?
        // now I want to set this emailIdToSend to Bean2 displayEmailId
    }
}
```

### page1.xhtml

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{bean1.username}" />
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean1.sendPassword()}" />
```

### Bean2.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean2")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean2 {
    public String displayEmailId;
    // getter and setter for this
    }
}
```

### page2.xhtml

```
 We have sent a new password on your registered email id at #{bean2.displayEmailId} 
<br />
Please login into system using the new password.
```

What I want is to set `bean1.var001` value to `bean2.var002`

Any idea how to do this?

I tried with below, but its not working.

```
Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2();
bean2.setVar002(var001);
```

---

### Edit 1

Well, what I am trying to do is doing "Forgot Password page".

On Page1, I ask for username. Once I have username and enter Submit, on back I have bean1. Here I check for username and send password on respective email id. Once email is send, i goes to page where I have back bean as bean2. On page2, I  want to display the email id so what I was trying to do is, after sending email, in bean1, set the email id to bean2 var002 and display that in page2.

Comment: Have a look over here - http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/

Comment: I see now. The scope of the variable is wrong, so when you make a back-redirect, the values are lost. Try to change the variable scope.

Comment: when I do back-redirect, **Yes, username should be gone**. I believe you meant back from `page2.xhtml` to `page1.xhtml`

Comment: Yes, that's what I ment.

Comment: @ConstantineNovykov : when I click back, there should not be username present in textfield... that is why I have view scope...

Comment: You could avoid showing it via javascript by display:none with the needed condition, but the other variable would still have the value.

Comment: @ConstantineNovykov : I didn't get what you mean

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24760/discussion-between-constantine-novykov-and-fahim-parkar)

Comment: Go through http://balusc.blogspot.in/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html.

Comment: I don't understand why don't you handle all this in the same managed bean, after all, it should be a `@ManagedBean @RequestScoped public class LoginBean` that handles all the *login* logic.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : if its same bean, when I goes to next page (page2), data in same bean is NULL as it is not initialized.

Comment: You can use a `@RequestScoped` (and any other kind of scope) managed bean in more than one page (obviously, doing this with `@ViewScoped` will result in a `@RequestScoped` method). Refer to the most basic JSF example: [JSF 2.0 Hello World Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/), change the managed bean from `@SessionScoped` to `@RequestScoped` and it will work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : I don't think request scope will work in that case... I will check and get back to you...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : can you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975354/weird-issue-action-welcome-working-however-action-hellobean-chkme-not). Some weird issue I am facing...